# Объединение списков словарей

Tags: python, list

Имеется список, внутри которого находятся другие списки. Вложенные списки могут быть либо строками, либо словарями. Нужно сгруппировать все вложенные списки-строки, идущие подряд, во вложенные списки.

Например:

Входные данные: `[["sth"], [{"a": 5}], [{"b": 10}], [{"test": 11}], ["test"], [{"c": 15}], [{"d": 20}]`

Выходные данные: `[["sth"], [{"a": 5}, {"b": 10}, {"test": 11}], ["test"], [{"c": 15}, {"d": 20}]`

```
test = [["sth"], [{"a": 5}], [{"b": 10}], [{"test": 11}], ["test"], [{"c": 15}], [{"d": 20}], ["test2"], [{"e": 25}]]
copy = test.copy()
print(copy)
temp = []

for item in copy:
    if not (isinstance(item[0], str)):
        print(f"Смотрим после {item[0]}")
        for j in range(copy.index(item), len(copy) - copy.index(item)):
            if not (isinstance(copy[j][0], str)):
                print(copy[j][0])
                temp.append(copy[j][0])
                copy[j][0] = ""
            else:
                break

print(copy.index(['']))
copy.insert(copy.index(['']), temp)
for item in copy:
    if (item == ['']):
        copy.pop(copy.index(item))

copy.pop(copy.index(['']))
```

Моя программа создает только первую группу списков

`[['sth'], [{'a': 5}, {'b': 10}, {'test': 11}], ['test'], [{'c': 15}], [{'d': 20}], ['test2'], [{'e': 25}]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Собираем в список элементы, пока одного типа, если разного, накопленный список добавляем в результат, а текущий элемент в новый аккумулятор

```
test = [["sth"], ['a'], [{"a": 5}], [{"b": 10}], [{"test": 11}], ["test"], [{"c": 15}], [{"d": 20}], ["test2"], [{"e": 25}]]

acc = [test[0][0]]            # сюда будем собирать внутренние списки
res = []                      # а сюда результат
for item in test[1:]:         # первый элемент уже там 
    if isinstance(item[0], type(acc[0])):
        acc.append(item[0])
    else:
        res.append(acc)
        acc = item
res.append(acc)              # последний  список

print(res)
```

Comment: Уже решил задачу, но ваше решение проще и почти в 2 раза короче моего. Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 2):

эту задачку вы уже решили, но может в будущем и такой вариант пригодится:

```
from itertools import groupby

test = [["sth"], ['a'], [{"a": 5}], [{"b": 10}], [{"test": 11}], ["test"], [{"c": 15}], [{"d": 20}], ["test2"], [{"e": 25}]]

res = [sum(g, []) for _, g in groupby(test, key=lambda x: type(x[0]))]

print(res)
# [['sth', 'a'], [{'a': 5}, {'b': 10}, {'test': 11}], ['test'], [{'c': 15}, {'d': 20}], ['test2'], [{'e': 25}]]
```